# How to count the amount of objects in a django joined table?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

My problem is simple: I have **Users** who own **Assets** or **Assets** which belong to Users If you prefer and I cannot make it to retrieve the number (count) of **Assets** each **User** has. I know this might be sound silly to most of you but I am new to python/django (coming from PHP/MySQL) and I do not know how things work here. I do not want to be engaged with raw SQL - this would be my last choice If nothing else works.

(*) I have removed all non-related raws from the code

**Users**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Assets**

```
class Assets(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', blank=True, null=True)

    # this is what I am playing with to retrieve the number of assets each user owns
    @classmethod
        def user_assets(self):
            return Assets.objects.filter(user=user).count()
```

**views.py**

```
class UserList(ListView):
    model = Users
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_assets'] = self.model.user_assets()
        return context
```

**template**

```
{% for user in object_list %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
         <td>
             {{ user_assets }}
         </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I get that number? I have read about aggregations, annotations and filters but can't really get it.

**EDIT:**

I am looking for a simple solution by using class based views and easily expandable (I may want to add other models later)

Comment: You need to use sql joins, if you don't want to mess around with raw sql you can try  django's [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and then [count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count), but you need foreign keys for this to work.

Comment: I have a foreign key from Assets to Users. Many assets belong to one user, but a two users can't have the same asset.

Comment: A yes, you're right, didn't notice that, try select related maybe it will do.

Comment: It doesn't. I tried "return cls.objects.select_related(None).count()" and "return cls.objects.select_related('assets').count()" and I always get the whole amount of assets.

Comment: What is cls there at the beginning? You need something like: `Assets.objects.prefetch_related('Users').filter(user=user).count()`

Comment: I am not sure this user=user works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `UserList` instead using model, use this queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class UserList(ListView):
    queryset = Users.objects.annotate(num_assets=Count('assets'))
```

and define your `user` field like so:

```
user = models.ForeignKey('Users', blank=True, null=True, related_name='assets')
```

then from template:

```
{{ user.num_assets }}
```

Also please remember, it's a good practice to use singular model names, to avoid confusion with reverse relation names..

Comment: I am getting "'ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'count'"

Comment: 'ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: I feel like I must import some lib

Comment: @RobDel oh I thnik the problem is, you're accessing class instead of an object (`self.model`) in your view.

Comment: @RobDel ok I made the final edition, try it out, you don't need the custom method in this case.

Comment: how should I call {{ user.num_assets }} when I am iterating with {% for %} ?

Comment: @RobDel Just use it instead of `{{ user_assets }}` inside the loop.

Comment: it worked and thank you very much but please explain :) Can you write a little more things... at least why you did what you did ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46636/discussion-between-mariodev-and-robdel)

Comment: I am getting correct readings for some users and not for all of them. Some appear to have 3x the amount of related objects. I can't really find the reason why...

Comment: @RobDel well I can't help you if I don't see the data and the generated query, also please use the chat for further discussion.

Comment: This is the query :  SELECT ••• FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `assets` ON ( `users`.`id` = `assets`.`user_id` ) LEFT OUTER JOIN `assets_ticket` ON ( `users`.`id` = `assets_ticket`.`user_id` ) GROUP BY `users`.`id` ORDER BY `users`.`lastname` ASC

Comment: I believe I found the issue - when a user has 1 assets and 4 tickets, he appear to have 4 assets/4 tickets. Another example, user has 1 asset and 9 tickets, he appears to have 9/9. In other cases (1/1, 1/0 etc.) the numbers are ok. It seems that it happens only in larger numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing weird things. Use the related managers that django give you instead. I'll write the view as a function based view:

**views.py**

```
def users_list(request):
    object_list = Users.objects.all()
    render(request, 'mytemplate.html', { 'object_list': object_list })
```

You can get the counts directly in the template via the RelatedManager:

**mytemplate.html**

```
{% for user in object_list %}
 <tr>
     <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
     <td>
         {{ user.assets_set.count }}
     </td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You could also annotate with a count. But learn to float before you swim :)

BTW, you should call your models "User" and "Asset", not Users and Assets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related), [count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) and pass user instance as argument to class method like so:

```
@classmethod
def user_assets(cls,user):
    return Assets.objects.select_related('Users').filter(user=user).count()
```

and then use it like so:

```
user = Users.objects.all()[0] # some user object (this assumes you have at least one user)
Assets.user_assets(user)
```

this should work fine, you can try it in the shell.

In your context this will be used like this:

```
user = self.model.all()[0] # or get or filter just get some particular user
context['user_assets'] = Assets.user_assets(user)
```

EDIT: added links, and Users.object.all() instead of Users.object.get(), also added example suited to your specific use case.

Comment: where am I supposed to put the second paragraph of your code? In views.py?

Comment: also the first part gives me an error "user_assets() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'"

Comment: yes, in views, are you sure you're passing user object to Assets? This pk=1 is just an example, you may not have user with id 1, the point is to pass user instance as argument to filter so that django narrows down selection to one instance of user.

Comment: type object 'Users' has no attribute 'all'. Any ideas ?