# Obtain in the same query the number of active and inactive users in django

Tags: django, orm

I have two models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

class Agent(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="agent")
```

I want to have the number of active and inactive users in a single request.
My request:

```
Agent.objects.annotate(
        actifs=Count(User.objects.values("id").filter("is_active")),
        inactifs=Count(User.objects.values("id").filter("is_active=False")),
    )
```

It does not work. How i can do it ?

Comment: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512647/how-to-count-the-amount-of-objects-in-a-django-joined-table' Please check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with an [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) where we use a [**`Count(…)`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id9) with a [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Agent.objects.aggregate(
    actifs=Count('user', filter=Q(user__is_active=True)),
    inactifs=Count('user', filter=Q(user__is_active=False))
)
```

This will return a dictionary with two entries: `actifs` and `inactifs`, for example:

```
{ 'actifs': 25, 'inactifs': 14 }
```